# The first int in one of two arrays is assigned 0 when I leave the for loop in which I assigned them values

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, long-integer

I am chopping off every digit from a long "n" starting with the last and assigning them into two alternating arrays x[] & y[] using a for loop.

I was expecting the first int in the array x[0] to be a non 0 int & when i print inside the loop it gives expected results but if i print after the loop, just the first int of the second array x[0] is 0? everything else works as intended?

```
    int x[8];
    int y[8];
    long n = 4003600000000014;
    int d = 0; 
    printf("x before: ");
    for (long j = n; j > 0; j /= 10)
    {
        y[d] = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        x[d] = n % 10;
        // debug to print x
        printf("%d, ", x[d]);
        n /= 10;
        d++;
    }
    //debug print
    printf("\n");
    printf("x after: ");
    for(int fu = 0; fu < 8; fu++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", x[fu]);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

the long "n" is just a test example it should be able to take any long

Comment: Why does the title say C# but the tags say C? Those are two different languages. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: Controlling the loop with a `j` that is divided by 10 once per iteration but filling in the arrays with an `n` that is divided by 10 twice per iteration is not going to work out well. Count how many times the loop will iterate because of the `j` handling and think about what that means for the values of `d` used in `y[d] = …` and `x[d] = …`.

Comment: The loop iterates 16 times, so `d` will be indexing out of bounds: undefined behaviour and my compilation crashes.

Comment: Whoops its c not c#. thanks for the advice I should have j divide by 100 every loop since I only need to iterate through half the longs digit length. It works now and I can understand why looping too long like that would cause n % 10 to assign as 0 but why does d becoming too large cycle the assignment of x[d] to overwright the first values but not for y[d]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the for loop

```
for (long j = n; j > 0; j /= 10)
{
    y[d] = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    x[d] = n % 10;
    // debug to print x
    printf("%d, ", x[d]);
    n /= 10;
    d++;
}
```

It has more iterations then the sizes of the arrays `x` and `y`.

In the for loop statement the variable `j` is divided by `10` only one time in each iteration of the loop

```
for (long j = n; j > 0; j /= 10)
                        ^^^^^^^
```

But within the body of the loop the variable `n` is divided by `10` two times

```
    y[d] = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    ^^^^^^^^
    x[d] = n % 10;
    // debug to print x
    printf("%d, ", x[d]);
    n /= 10;
    ^^^^^^^
    d++;
```

As a result within the for loop there are accesses of memory beyond the arrays `x` and `y`.

You could rewrite your loop the following way

```
for (long j = n; j > 0; )
{
    y[d] = j % 10;
    j /= 10;
    x[d] = j % 10;
    // debug to print x
    printf("%d, ", x[d]);
    j /= 10;
    d++;
}
```

Comment: Dividing n by 10 has nothing to do with it. It is `j` divided by 10 that determines the number of iterations. Once `j` is set to `n` at the beginning of the loop it does not matter what happens to `n`. The problem is the size of the two arrays.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think you are mistfaken.

Comment: Please look again. In my test program the loop runs 16 times, no matter what operations on `n` are commented out (or more added). The loop depends only on the *initial* value of `n`.

Comment: @WeatherVane You have just confirmed my correct answer. :) Think one more about the problem.:)

Comment: The loop depends only on the *initial* value of `n`. Have you **run the code**? When I implement your "solution" the code still crashes. After `j =n`, the `n` only affects the value written to the arrays, while still overflow.

Comment: @WeatherVane Please, reread my answer and see the rewritten for loop in my answer.:)

Comment: Yes, I've re-read it now. I downvoted your first answer which seemed not to correct the problem, because it didn't make another division of `j`. Thanks.

Comment: @WeatherVane It seems it is a problem with my English.:)